# Access Apache environment variables from mod_perl without %ENV

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl, mod-perl2

I using Apache 2.2 and mod_perl 2.0.4.  I want to retrieve the value of an environment variable named "A_VARIABLE" in a mod_perl handler which was set in an Apache configuration file as:

```
SetEnv A_VARIABLE  "some value"
```

In the [mod_perl documentation about the PerlSetEnv configuration option](https://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/config.html#PerlSetupEnv), it says the following:

> PerlSetupEnv On will allow you to access the environment variables like $ENV{REQUEST_URI}, which are available under CGI. However, when programming handlers, there are always better ways to access these variables through the Apache API. Therefore, it is recommended to turn it Off except for scripts which absolutely require it. See PerlSetupEnv Off.

Is there a way to access to read that variable **without** using the %ENV hash as the documentation implies?  If so, please provide a short example on how to do so.

Comment: maybe with https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache2::RequestRec#subprocess_env ? I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @ysth - That's what I thought too, but I can't seem to access any variables from that method. To be clear, that table appears to be empty.

Comment: don't have time to try, but this looks like it: https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/ServerUtil.html#C_dir_config_

Comment: @ysth - Unfortunately that method only works with variables set using PerlSetVar and PerlAddVar in the Apache config. I'm trying to get a value set with SetEnv because the value is also used outside of mod_perl. I'm trying to avoid having to configure the variable twice, once with SetEnv and once with PerlSetVar.